# PyTables retrieve maximum and minimum values?

Tags: timestamp, max, min, hdf5, pytables

I've created a Python script which receives time-series data off a socket and writes it via PyTables to an HDF5 file like so:

```
#Define description object to pass to the table constructor
class DataPoint(tb.IsDescription):
    timestamp = tb.Time64Col() #UNIX timestamp
    value = tb.Float32Col() #Value
```

Each time the script runs it *will* receive some data-history which will have previously been saved to the file along with fresh unsaved data. I would like to ensure that timestamped rows aren't duplicated in the file and so need to filter the arrivals.

For this I need to check the extent of the data already in the file i.e. maximum and minimum timestamp values present.

Is anyone please able to demonstrate the query logic for retrieving the rows with maximum and minimum timestamps?

Comment: Pytables returns a numpy array. Use the `.amax()` and `.amin()` operators on the timestamp column and you should be set. You can use `.where()`, and/or `.argmax()` / `.argmin()` to get the indices of each max/min. See this topic for 4 different ways to get a column of data as a numpy array:  [PyTables cols method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254831/)

Comment: Help! How do I put those calls together! Am new at PyTables ;-)

Comment: Only the call to read the HDF5 table/dataset is a pytable call. The rest is numpy functionality. MCVE provided below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, a simple example with `floats` that demonstrates reading a HDF5 table/dataset to a numpy array, then using `.max()` and `.min()` operators to get Max/Min, then `.argmax()` and `.argmin()` to get the indices for each. I am not familiar with `Time64Col()` for UNIX timestamps and how the operators will work. I'll let you figure that out. :-)

The first 2 examples extract a single column with different PyTables methods.
The third method extracts the whole table to an array, then indexes with the field/column name.
Use the technique that makes the most sense to you.

Note that the data is generated randomly, so the output will be random too. However, output from the first and third methods should always be identical.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

# Create h5 file with 1 dataset

h5f = tb.open_file('SO_55266365.h5', 'w')

mydtype = np.dtype([('param1',float),('param2',float),('param3',float)])

arr = np.random.rand(500,3)
recarr = np.core.records.array(arr,dtype=mydtype)

h5f.create_table('/', 'set1', obj=recarr )

# Close, then Reopen file READ ONLY
h5f.close()

h5f = tb.open_file('SO_55266365.h5', 'r')

# Get first column (param1)
p1 = h5f.root.set1.col('param1')
print ('param 1 Max = ' , p1.max(), 'at row =' , p1.argmax() )
print ('param 1 Min = ' , p1.min(), 'at row =' , p1.argmin() )

# Get second column (param2)
p2 = h5f.root.set1.read(field='param2')
print ('param 2 Max = ' , p2.max(), 'at row =' , p2.argmax() )
print ('param 2 Min = ' , p2.min(), 'at row =' , p2.argmin() )

# Get all 3 columns
# (index to get column when referencing the object)
p123 = h5f.root.set1.read()
print ('param 1 Max = ' , p123['param1'].max(), 'at row =' , p123['param1'].argmax() )
print ('param 1 Min = ' , p123['param1'].min(), 'at row =' , p123['param1'].argmin() )

h5f.close()
```

Comment: I hacked your example to reflect my hdf5 file name & structure. It then worked as-is on the Time64Col() type.  I wonder; should the comment on the final example read: # (index to get *row* when referencing the object)?

Comment: Nice. Regarding your question, it depends on which index we're talking about. I was referring to  `p123['param1']` to reference the `param1` column in array `p123`. But, you are correct: the `.argmax()` and `.argmin()` operators get the row index for that column. :-)

Comment: So in these examples `.read()` brings the entire table into memory. How could the max/min timestamp rows be selected with an in-kernel query?

Comment: How big is your dataset? is memory an issue? I haven't tried to find the Max/Min with an in-kernel query. Based on the docs, I don't see a way to define a condition to find them. You could use `'timestamp>a_value'` to find candidate rows. You will need a good estimate of the max value (and the same for min values with less than condition). You could save Max/Min values as attributes with the dataset, then reference them each time you add data. If you do this, remember to update them after the update!

Comment: Nice thinking, many thanks! Have implemented storing the max/min timestamp values as attributes and updating after appending.  Memory is not yet an issue, just want to ensure my code will scale with the data.